# Android GCMIntentService onMessage context issue

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement GCM to my app in Android. The server and client side setup seems to be right, because the onMessage method is called when I "push" a string from the server side. I can read the extras from the intent, however, using a notification or a Toast message doesn't work. The phone doesn't show anything, even with the app running, so I guess something isn't right with the context object I use from the callback.
Here's the revelvant part of the manifest.xml, where PACKAGE is the base package.

```
<receiver
   android:name="PACKAGE.gcm.GCMReceiver"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
             <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="PACKAGE" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
   android:name="PACKAGE.gcm.GCMIntentService"
   android:enabled="true" />
</application>

<permission
    android:name="PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="PACKAGE.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
</manifest>
```

Now the onMessage Method:

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (DEBUG)
        {
            System.out.println("[GCMIntentService] Message Received! " + intent.getStringExtra("message"));
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        // int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(0, tickerText, when);

        CharSequence contentTitle = "Some Notification";
        CharSequence contentText = tickerText + " some more text";

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, null);

        final int HELLO_ID = 1;

        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

    }
```

The Toast and the Notification aren't working. I call the service and registration routines in the onCreate of the first Activity, wich is used as Splash and closed after a few seconds. Might that have something to do with it?

Comment: Not to do with the question, but you shouldn't really use `System.out.println("..");`
Use `Log.d(TAG,"Message);` (or v,e,w,i).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a `Context` issue.

GCM reciever runs in an intent service which in its self runs on a separate thread.

To show a toast just call from inside a UIThread. Which you can do like so:

```
Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
h.post(new Runnable(){

    Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

});
```

This will now post on your UI thread and you will then see the toast!

*(You will need to make your local variable's `final` for them to be executed by the anonymous class)*

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! and for the Notification, how should I create it? I don't need the app to be running to launch the notification, so the handler trick  shouldn't work there. Should I still use the context object from the intent in the onMessage?

Comment: Nevermind, it seems the notification needs to have an icon. Putting any integer there won't trigger the notification.

Comment: @MetalCraneo for the notification I would recommend the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html that way you can add jellybean features that will degrade gracefully. :) but yes generally the application context is fine, which is what you have there.